# Display PDF files based on user roles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently working on a website being developing using ASP.NET and C#. I'm fairly new to ASP and C# so I apologise if I'm making an obvious mistake. The website I am working on has a login page which displays relevant PDF files. The client now wants to rebuild that by only displaying certain PDF files to the end user depending on their role. I have looked into Role based. My problem is I have over 100 PDF files which need to be displayed. What would be the best approach for this? Where would I store the roles in my DB?

Shall I do something like

```
if(User.IsInRole("Management"))
    {
        //Do something 
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in Membership- and Roleproviders (e.g. http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/) or customize/override any of these in case you don't want the standard-table structure these providers bring with them.

If you combine the two providers and use the "default" implementation you can actually do it like you suggested yourself in your question, without any further implementation. It would be just configuration in your web.config then.

You can then introduce new roles and user/role mappings in the tables, that ASP.NET automagically created for you in the DB.

Here is some example how to override them: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers

Comment: Will it be the same for ASP.NET because the links seem to be for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Yes, that's not specific to ASP.NET MVC. In fact, this mechanism is very old, long before MVC was born ;)